# BeautifulSoup decompose multiple classes of an element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

I want to remove certain span elements, all up about 10 individual classes. I can do this tediously with repeating my code 10 times, but that is not the correct way to learn.

This is what I got working, that I want to simplify:

```
for span in table_tag.find_all("span", {'class':'class1'}):
    span.decompose()
for span in table_tag.find_all("span", {'class':'class2'}):
    span.decompose()
for span in table_tag.find_all("span", {'class':'class3'}):
    span.decompose()
```

This is what I tried but it didn't remove anything:

```
remove = table_tag.find_all('class1','class2','class3')
for span in table_tag.find_all("span", {'class': remove}):
    span.decompose()
```

The BeautifulSoup documentation just doesn't hit home with me about how to decompose multiple elements in one command. Also when I go above 5 classes in the find_all command, I get an error that find_all takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given. Obviously I am using the command wrong, just need some help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
classes = ['class1', 'class2'....]
for i in classes:
    for span in table_tag.find_all("span", {'class': i}):
        span.decompose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector with comma `,`:

```
for span in table_tag.select('.class1, .class2, .class3'):
    span.decompose()
```